# Don't generate log parameters unnecessarily

Tags: log4net

I have some log statements like this:

```
_log.InfoFormat("Log some stuff: {0}", string.Join(", ", someList));
```

If I set the log level below Info then these statements are omitted from the log file, but the parameters (the string.Join stuff) are still generated unnecessarily. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
_log.InfoFormat("Log some stuff: {0}", () => string.Join(", ", someList));
```

I didn't see anything in intellisense for this. Are there any good (concise) workarounds, or other frameworks that can do deferred parameter generation?

Comment: I just wrap it in an if statement.  It's not elegant, but it's straightforward and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a little extension method:

```
public static void InfoDeferred(this ILog source, string message, params Func<object>[] deferredArgs)
{
    if(source.IsInfoEnabled)
    {
        var args = new List<object>();
        foreach(var arg in deferredArgs)
        {
            args.Add(arg());
        }

        source.InfoFormat(message, args.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
_log.InfoDeferred("Log some stuff: {0}", () => string.Join(", " someList));
```